# Sort when values are None or empty strings python

Tags: python, list, sorting, null

I have a list with dictionaries in which I sort them on different values. I'm doing it with these lines of code:

```
def orderBy(self, col, dir, objlist):
    if dir == 'asc':
        sorted_objects = sorted(objlist, key=lambda k: k[col])
    else:
        sorted_objects = sorted(objlist, key=lambda k: k[col], reverse=True)
    return sorted_objects
```

Now the problem is that I occasionally have null values or empty strings when I try to sort and then it all breaks down.

I'm not sure but i think that this is the exception that's thrown: unorderable types: NoneType() < NoneType(). It occurs when there is None values on the column I'm trying to sort. For empty string values it works although they end up first in the list but I would like them to be last.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Exactly *how* does it break down?

Comment: Side note: don't use an `if..else` when you can just do `sorted(..., reverse=dir != 'asc')` here.

Comment: You'll need to give us some sample data here; show us what happens with that and what yu expected to happen instead.

Comment: This is a part of an ajax call from the DataTables pluin so i just get an error that it didn't get the correct data back. I'm going to try some debugging to get some data now.

Comment: I'm not sure but i think that this is the exception that's thrown: 
`unorderable types: NoneType() < NoneType()`.
It occurs when there is None values on the column I'm trying to sort. For empty string values it works although they end up first in the list but I would like them to be last.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want the `None` and `''` values to appear last, you can have your `key` function return a tuple, so the list is sorted by the natural order of that tuple. The tuple has the form `(is_none, is_empty, value)`; this way, the tuple for a `None` value will be `(1, 0, None)`, for `''` is `(0, 1, '')` and for anything else `(0, 0, "anything else")`. Thus, this will sort proper strings first, then empty strings, and finally `None`.

Example:

```
>>> list_with_none = [(1,"foo"), (2,"bar"), (3,""), (4,None), (5,"blub")]
>>> col = 1
>>> sorted(list_with_none, key=lambda k: (k[col] is None, k[col] == "", k[col])) 
[(2, 'bar'), (5, 'blub'), (1, 'foo'), (3, ''), (4, None)]
```

Comment: @tobias_k : One Question...does the order of elements in `(k[col] is None, k[col] == "", k[col]))` afftect the order in the output list?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور Of course, that's the whole idea behind this. The tuples will be sorted by their first elemens, and if those are equal, then by the second element, and so on.

Comment: How will it work with multiple keys? I tried  sorted(a, key=lambda k: [(k[col] is None,  k[col]) for col in keys]  )  but getting weird results.

Comment: @KanchanSrivastava What is `keys` here?

Comment: assuming list of dictionaries instead of tuple, how will it work?